# Programmatically using constraints on a button that is also programmatically made

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm trying to get my Facebook login button (top center of the screenshot) to be below the "Register or Login Button" by using constraints, but I'm not sure which constraints to use and how to use them. I'm quite new to Swift 3 and I have not done constraint programmatically yet, so any help would be welcomed! Initially I just used the x and y position in the CGRect to place the button, but I noticed that on different device, the button would not be in the same place, so I'm trying to use constraints now.

It looks like this:

[image]

this is the code regarding my button in my viewDidLoad:

```
let fbLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()

view.addSubview(fbLoginButton)

fbLoginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width - 
        100, height: 40)

self.view.addSubview(fbLoginButton)

fbLoginButton.center.x = view.frame.width/2
```

I tried doing:

```
let verticalSpace = NSLayoutConstraint(
    item: self, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: fbLoginButton,
    attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 0.75, constant: 0)
```

but that led me to get this error:

> Constraint items must each be an instance of UIView, or UILayoutGuide.

Comment: Assuming you are doing this in a view controller then `item` should be `self.view` not `self` - as the error message say the item must be a `UIView` - a `UIViewController` is not a `UIView`.  Also make sure you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` on your `fbLoginButton`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try code I had added a button "send" programatically just below a button "Show Alert" which is added using storyboard

```
@IBOutlet weak var showAlertButton: UIButton!

func AddButton(){


    let sendButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    sendButton.setTitle("Send", for: UIControlState())
    sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(sendButton)

    sendButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: showAlertButton.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    sendButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: showAlertButton.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    sendButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: showAlertButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    sendButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    sendButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: showAlertButton.heightAnchor).isActive = true


}
```

[image]